# is this use case well structure?

Tags: object-oriented, uml, use-case

I'm trying to create a use case that make sense, and i am a little bit confused with the alternate path i think i am doing it in the wrong way, the system should tell the admin when a shared playlist was opened from the receptor, i appreciate your help.

```
notify when playlist is opened

1-the user share a playlist
2-the receiver get the shared playlist email
3-the receiver click the shared playlist link URL
4-the system get the request email link
    4.1 the system get an invalid link
        4.1.2 the link was already used
5-the system send an email to the admin to notify them
    5.1 the system show an invalid message
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [UML sequence diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) to make your case more clear. If you make a sequence diagram then I believe that will help you.

Comment: this reads more like a comment, see [answer]